# Jenkins credentials - how to use .P12 certificate

Tags: jenkins

I have an issue with certificates and I am not even sure if I chose the right way to go...
Long story short.. I need my jenkins job to download something during build from website where I need to use certificate authentication - I got .p12 and .cert certificates.
I thought I will just import them via Credentials plugin in Jenkins and so I will be able to use them in jobs, but I can't do it.

**What I've done so far:**
I've created keystore xxx.jks and imported p12 and cert in it. 
Tried to add the path to it to "From a PKCS#12 file on Jenkins master", but getting message:
`Could not load keystore
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.`

I've tried to upload the certificate from Jenkins, but got this:
`Could retrieve key "cert alias". You may need to provide a password
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: null`

I would appreciate any advice or suggestion including some useful documentation (I've tried, but I can't find anything useful for me honestly).

Thank you very much.

Comment: What command are you using to authenticate with the web server?

Comment: After all I was just thinking to use wget (because I just need to download one file from that location) - so maybe I should just import that certificate to jenkins master and then just run simple script with wget?  I thought I could somehow use the credentials in jenkins, but I guess that is not good idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

- You can import the certificate to somewhere on the Jenkins machine, and reference that absolute location with your `wget` command.
- You can place the certificate into the SVN so that it becomes part of workspace checkout, use relative location with your `wget` command.
- You can use `File Parameter` for the job configuration, which will prompt you to upload a file to the job's workspace, however you need to provide that everytime the job runs.
- Use **[Plain Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plain+Credentials+Plugin)**, which has "secret Zip file" functionality that duplicates **[Build Secret Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Secret+Plugin)** (which has been deprecated, but really is what you want)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, SVN + wget work for now, but I will try other tips as well.

Comment: @Slav I see you where helpful with this scenario, would you know how i could resolve the issue i have here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141737/jenkins-and-ssl-certificates any help appreciated

Comment: @Richlewis Hi, I've looked at your question, but don't think I can help. I did upvote it for more visibility though. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for looking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this with the Credentials Binding Plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin

Store the file in the secure Credentials section of Jenkins as a File. Then to access the file use something like the below scripted code:

```
stage('Get orders JSON from web service') {
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'certID', variable: 'MY_CERT')]) {
        ORDERS_JSON = sh(
           script: "curl --cert $MY_CERT https://host.com/api/orders -k",
           returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
    }
}
```