# Jenkins and SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, curl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Firstly my exposure and experience with certificates is limited so I am trying to use this as a learning experience as well as obtaining an answer.

Using Jenkins I would like to be able to make a curl request as part of my build that uses a certificate (.p12) to authenticate.

Example

```
curl --cert /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/develop-pipeline/../certificates/dev_cert.p12:password https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/MYSTATS-1234
```

So I have a Desktop certificate (private key) which I have saved onto the machine where Jenkins runs, but I also understand that I need a CA certificate to authorise this private key (hope this is correct so far).

When I have run the curl command from the terminal on the Jenkins machine I had a popup that asked me did I want to use the cert within the keychain to authorise and I clicked always allow, so command line curl requests always work.

However when I run this as part of a Jenkins build I get

```
(58) SSL: Can't load the certificate "/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/develop-pipeline/../certificates/dev_cert.p12" and its private key: OSStatus -25308
```

The path to the cert is correct as the directory structure is

```
develop-pipeline
certificates
  dev_cert.p12
```

What I don't understand is that if I don't provide a password

```
curl --cert /Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/develop-pipeline/../certificates/dev_cert.p12 https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/MYSTATS-1234
```

I get the message:

```
SSL The certificate "/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/develop-pipeline/dev_cert.p12" requires a password
```

So it has found the certificate ?

Also providing an incorrect password yields

```
 SSL: Incorrect password for the certificate "/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/develop-pipeline/dev_cert.p12" and its private key.
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

[This Github comment](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/573#issuecomment-254436739) helped me sorting out the curl issue on OSX. So in my case installing curl via Homebrew with OpenSSL flags did the trick.